# HBase Put Data doesnt work

Tags: hbase

have the following problem when adding data in a table (via hbase shell) with the following scheme

```
create 'student','info','vorl'
```

Add the following statement does not work

```
put 'student','student_1234','info:name','Mustermann','vorl:1','Datenbanksysteme'
```

what am I doing wrong where is the error, the 2 columns but families are generated correctly
Ever Thanks for feedback

Comment: "Does not work" is _never_ a sufficient problem description. How does it fail? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: hbase(main):017:0> put 'student','780533','info:name','Berg','vorl:1','DB'

ERROR: wrong number of arguments (6 for 5)

Answer (score 3):

You should explain clearly what you *want* to do and what does not work as mentioned in the comments by Matt Ball.

I assume that you want to create a row 'student_1234' in the table 'student' and add the value 'Mustermann' in the column 'name' (itself in the column family 'info') as well as the value 'Datenbanksysteme' in the column '1' (itself in the column family 'vorl')

According to the help of the put command :

```
To put a cell value into table 't1' at
row 'r1' under column 'c1' marked with the time 'ts1', do:

hbase> put 't1', 'r1', 'c1', 'value', ts1
```

Therefore, you should type the following statements to achieve the result described above

```
hbase(main):004:0> put 'student', 'student_1234', 'info:name','Mustermann'
0 row(s) in 0.1340 seconds

hbase(main):005:0> put 'student', 'student_1234', 'vorl:1','Datenbanksysteme'
0 row(s) in 0.0330 seconds

hbase(main):006:0> scan 'student'
ROW                                      COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                         
student_1234                            column=info:name, timestamp=1361823735604, value=Mustermann                                                         
student_1234                            column=vorl:1, timestamp=1361823752261, value=Datenbanksysteme                                                      
 1 row(s) in 0.0610 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks, but So you can not add data to a statement both families add columns?

Comment: all data with same timestamp ? how

Comment: Why do you want to have all data with the same timestamp ? You can pass the desired timestamp as fifth argument of the put command